# Closing/Hiding previous UL LI element when a new UL LI element is clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need your help.

For some strange reason it appears that if the user does not makes a selection in the left box and then clicks on the right box then both menus are left open per say. How can the javascript code be modified such that if the user moves the focus to another box that the previous box returns to its default state and the next box is opened? I have attached a before and after picture:

[image]

Here is the complete HTML Markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
* {
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  font-size: 9pt;
}
.select {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.select dd, .select dt, .select ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.select dd {
  position: relative;
}
.select a, .select a:visited {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
.select dt:hover, .select dd ul:hover {
  border-color: rgb(128,128,128);
}
.select dd ul li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(112, 146, 190);
  color: #FFF;
}
.select dt {
  background: url(arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right center;
  display: block;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
  width: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.select dt span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  height: 15px;
}
.select dd ul {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
  border-top: 0;
  display: none;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}
.select dd ul li a {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  display: block;
}
.selected {
  background: rgb(195, 195, 195);
}
.header-list, .header-list:hover {
  padding-left: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  cursor: pointer;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".select dt").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var select = $(this).closest('.select');
        select.find('ul').toggle();
        select.find("dt, dd ul").css('border-color', 'rgb(128,128,128)')

        select.find("dt, span, dd ul").css('background-color', 'rgb(255,255,196)')


    });

    $(".select dd ul li a").click(function(e) {
        var text = $(this).html();
        var select = $(this).closest('.select');

        if ((select.data('val') == 'multiple') && (e.ctrlKey)) {
            e.stopPropagation()
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            select.find('dt span').html("(" + select.find('a.selected').length + ")");

        }
        else {
            var text = $(this).html();
            select.find("dd a").removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            select.find("dt span").html(text);
            //select.find("dt a").css("background-color", "");
            select.find("dd ul").hide();
        }
    });

    $(document).bind('click', function() {
        $(".select dd ul").hide();
        $(".select dt, .select dd ul").css('border-color', '');
    });

});
</script>

</head>

<body>


<table>

<tr>

<td>

<dl class="select">
    <dt><span id="vegetables"></span></dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Carrots</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Celery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Brocoli</a></li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>

</td>

<td>
<dl class="select">
    <dt><span id="fruits"></span></dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Apples</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Oranges</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bananas</a></li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>

</td>
</tr>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
    $('.select').not(select).find('ul').hide();
```

in the `$(".select dt").click` handler

---

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".select dt").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        var select = $(this).closest('.select');
        // close all other selects
        $('.select').not(select).find('ul').hide();
      
        select.find('ul').toggle();
        select.find("dt, dd ul").css('border-color', 'rgb(128,128,128)')

        select.find("dt, span, dd ul").css('background-color', 'rgb(255,255,196)')


    });

    $(".select dd ul li a").click(function(e) {
        var text = $(this).html();
        var select = $(this).closest('.select');

        if ((select.data('val') == 'multiple') && (e.ctrlKey)) {
            e.stopPropagation()
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            select.find('dt span').html("(" + select.find('a.selected').length + ")");

        }
        else {
            var text = $(this).html();
            select.find("dd a").removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');
            select.find("dt span").html(text);
            //select.find("dt a").css("background-color", "");
            select.find("dd ul").hide();
        }
    });

    $(document).bind('click', function() {
        $(".select dd ul").hide();
        $(".select dt, .select dd ul").css('border-color', '');
    });

});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: Segoe UI;
  font-size: 9pt;
}
.select {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.select dd, .select dt, .select ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.select dd {
  position: relative;
}
.select a, .select a:visited {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
.select dt:hover, .select dd ul:hover {
  border-color: rgb(128,128,128);
}
.select dd ul li a:hover {
  background-color: rgb(112, 146, 190);
  color: #FFF;
}
.select dt {
  background: url(arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right center;
  display: block;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
  width: 180px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.select dt span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  padding: 4px;
  height: 15px;
}
.select dd ul {
  background: #fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
  border-left: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(170, 170, 170);
  border-top: 0;
  display: none;
  left: 0px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 200px;
  list-style: none;
}
.select dd ul li a {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  display: block;
}
.selected {
  background: rgb(195, 195, 195);
}
.header-list, .header-list:hover {
  padding-left: 3px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: italic;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>

<tr>

<td>

<dl class="select">
    <dt><span id="vegetables"></span></dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Carrots</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Celery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Brocoli</a></li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>

</td>

<td>
<dl class="select">
    <dt><span id="fruits"></span></dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Apples</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Oranges</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Bananas</a></li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```